# $f_E = \nu[f_F \,\vert\, \mathcal{B}_E]$, where $f_K$ is the Radon-Nykodim derivative.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, conditional-probability, radon-nikodym

Let $X = \mathbb{N}ˆG$, where $G$ is a countable group and, for $K \subset G$ let $X_K = \mathbb{N}^K$. Consider also $\mathcal{B}_K$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets of the form $[w]= \{x \in X \,:\, x(k) = w(k), \forall k \in K\}$, with $w \in X_K$.

Also, given $K \Subset G$ and $\mu, \nu$ be two probability measures such that $\nu << \mu$.  Denote by $f_K$ The Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu\vert_K$ with respect to $\nu\vert_K$, where $\mu\vert_K$ and $\nu\vert_K$ denote the restrictions of $\mu$ and $\nu$ to $\mathcal{B}_K$, respectively.

I want to prove that if $E, F \Subset G$ are such that $E \subseteq F$ and $\mu$ and $\nu$ be the ones given. Then $f_{E} = \nu[f_{F} \,\vert\, \mathcal{B}_E]$.

I notice that what I did was wrong. Basically, my idea was to prove that, for  every $B \in \mathcal{B}_E$, it holds that
\begin{equation*}
    \int_B f_E \, d\nu = \int_B f_F \, d\nu.
\end{equation*}

But for that I used that $\mathcal{B}_E \subseteq \mathcal{B}_F$, if it is the case that $E\subset F$. When I was reviewing, I noticed that what happens is exactly the opposite.

Here is what I did (recalling that I used something that is wrong):
from the properties of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, we have that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu(B) = \int_B f_E d\nu,
\end{equation*}
for all $B \in \mathcal{B}_E$, and that
\begin{equation*}
    \mu(B) = \int_B f_F d\nu,
\end{equation*}
for all $B \in \mathcal{B}_F$. Thus, for $B \in \mathcal{B}_E \subset \mathcal{B}_F$,  \begin{equation*}
    \int_B f_E d\nu = \mu(B) = \int_B f_E d\nu.
\end{equation*}

Comment: You have some typos or confusing notations. For example, you write $\mathcal{B}_K$ and $X_K$, without $K$ appearing before. You also write $[w]$, without explaining this notation. Can you clarify some of these notations?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur, I edited the question. Hope it is clear now!

Comment: Perhaps two some follow up questions, if that's okay: $\mu$ and $\nu$ are measures on $G$ or on $X$? Does $K\Subset G$, mean $\overline{K}$ is compact and $\overline{K}\subseteq G$? And when you write $\nu[f_F\vert \mathcal{B}_E]$, do you mean as in conditional expectation with respect to a sigma algebra?

Comment: Why do you think that $\mathcal{B}_E\not\subset \mathcal{B}_F$? The Right side of the inclusion seems to be generated by more cylinder sets. Also, is the conditional $\nu[f_F\vert \mathcal{B}_E]$ well defined if $f_F$ is just $\mathcal{B}_F$-measurable and you don't have this inclusion?